# RabbitMQ Java Client Asynchronous Topic Receipt

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a program that sends and receives messages over an exchange. My program needs to continue execution regardless of whether there is a message for it in the queue. Almost all the tutorials have blocking examples:

```
while (true) {
     QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
     System.out.println("Message: " + new String(delivery.getBody()));
     ch.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
}
```

I came across what I understand to be the asynchronous version i.e., the handleDelivery function is called (callback) when a message is available in the queue:

```
 boolean autoAck = false;
 channel.basicConsume(queueName, autoAck, "myConsumerTag",
 new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
     @Override
     public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                Envelope envelope,
                                AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                byte[] body)
         throws IOException
     {
         String routingKey = envelope.getRoutingKey();
         String contentType = properties.contentType;
         long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
         // (process the message components here ...)
         channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
     }
 });
```

After reading over the documentation I'm still unsure whether the above code snippet is indeed asynchronous and I still can't figure out how to get the actual message that was sent. Some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out trying the second code snippet I can say that it is possible it does what you want.  However it presumably does this but using a thread internally (which will be blocked while waiting for a new message).  What I do is stick the while loop in a new Thread so that only that thread is blocked and the rest of your program continues asyncrhonously

Comment: From the documentation: "Callbacks to Consumers are dispatched on a thread separate from the thread managed by the Connection. This means that Consumers can safely call blocking methods on the Connection or Channel, such as queueDeclare, txCommit, basicCancel or basicPublish. Each Channel has its own dispatch thread. For the most common use case of one Consumer per Channel, this means Consumers do not hold up other Consumers. If you have multiple Consumers per Channel be aware that a long-running Consumer may hold up dispatch of callbacks to other Consumers on that Channel."

Comment: Just to follow up on my previous comment because I ran out of space. So to me it sounds like its starting its own thread and waiting for a message. Meanwhile the rest of my program can run as required. But again, the problem is that I don't know how to get at the message.

Comment: I dont understand your question.  Delivery.getBody() is the message. In the second example you have byte[] body which is the message too.  What else do you need?

Comment: Sometime I'm just really thick... Yes @robthewolf you are right the data is in the body. To get the actual text I had to convert the byte array to a string: System.out.println(new String(body));. Just as a follow up, based on some testing this is asynchronous. Thanks for your help!